# Viewport width based unit-less value

Tags: css, layout

I have this css that I use to set size variables that increase by a certain set ratio. If I set the ratio to 2 each size step doubles the previous one.

```
:root {
 --ratio: 2;
 
 --s0: 1rem;
 --s1: calc(var(--s0) * var(--ratio));
 --s2: calc(var(--s1) * var(--ratio));
 --s3: calc(var(--s2) * var(--ratio)); 
}

.box {
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: black;
 padding: 0 15px;
 color: white;
}

.s0 {
 height: var(--s0);
}

.s1 {
 height: var(--s1);
}

.s2 {
 height: var(--s2);
}

.s3 {
 height: var(--s3);
}
```

This results in the following boxes:
[image]

I would like the ratio variable to be a fluid value based on viewport width. So that I can use a lower ratio on smaller viewports, and higher ratio on bigger viewports.

Is this possible? I'm guessing I need a unit-less value that is somehow related to the vw.

Comment: Why isn't viewport height important? And what sets the width of each element?

Comment: Because I want the ratio to be based on vw. The width of the elements is irrelevant. The boxes are only a visual representation of the scale.

Comment: If the ratio is to be proportional in some way to the viewport width (rather than a step function) then you could resort to JS, read window.innerWidth and set a CSS property (variable) --ratio (e.g. on body) as required. If it's stepped then CSS media queries would do it without JS.